# How to get "In-shorts" app like vertical scrolling in swift Programmatically i.e without storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I would like to enable vertical scrolling in my IOS application, where one UIView is placed below another and I can swipe it up to show the next UIView below it. As in very similar to the In-shorts news app. It would be helpful if there were any libraries I could use to do so in swift programmatically as I am not using storyboards.
   If not, a simple solution to obtain vertical scrolling where I can place one UIView below another would do as well.Can I do so by using a UIScrollView? also how do I add the views to the scrollView and give the scrollView Width and height constraints? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you used the uitableview with pageing enabled concept, the transition  conflict will occur on swipe

Comment: So I need to use a tableView? I thought i could use a simple scrollView and place Views one below the other.